# Need help with high voltage rectification

Tags: diodes, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I have a necessity to implement a bridge rectifier, the bridge will be fed from residential power, stepped up with a transformer at 409Vac rms @ 8amps. The power will be used continually and not in a pulsed or delayed manner. Are any of these up for the task? If not how should I go about rectifying?
[Rectifier Module](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/GBJ50005-GBJ5010(GBJ)-B.pdf)
[Discrete Diode](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IDW75D65D1-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a0bf290014a5670e9cd3eeb)

Comment: You do realize that 409V at 8 amps is over 3.2 kilowatts. What is your residential source? You would need at least a 30 amp circuit (at 120 vac) for this application, probably more for safety.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but this seems like a textbook exercise to me.

- look for a set of diodes (or a bridge) that is rated for those values (preferrably with a good margin).
- A good heatsink will probably be required
- determine the ripple on the output that you can accept, from that calculate the required capacitance.
- select a capacitor *that can candle the ripple current that will occur* (and the voltage, of course)
- select a suitable way to reduce the start-up current (resistor, PTC, ...)

Or are you just asking for the diodes? With 409V rms the rectified voltage (on your capacitor) will be sqrt( 2 ) * 409V. That is the reverse voltage your diodes must be able to handle. The table from your datasheet makes life easy by mentioning both this maximum reverse voltage *and* the RMS voltage.

[image]

If you can't find a suitbale bridge or single diodes that can handle your voltage difference you could consider using two in series (with resistors to divide the blocking voltage evenly).